# PHP Image Upload Issue: Replacing Previous Image When Uploading Multiple Posts with Images

Tags: php

I'm facing an issue with my PHP application's image upload functionality. The scenario is as follows:

I have a form where users can create a post and upload an image associated with the post.
When I upload the first post with an image, everything works fine, and the image is correctly saved to the server Folder name **Uploads** with a name (e.g., **post1_image.jpg**).
However, the problem arises when I try to upload a second post with a different image but having the same name as the first image (e.g., **post1_image.jpg**). Instead of saving it as a new image, it replaces the previous image associated with the first post.
How can I modify my PHP code to ensure that each uploaded image gets a unique name and doesn't overwrite any existing images? Here's a simplified version of my current PHP code for handling the image upload:

```
<?php 
    include "config.php"; // Connection with server

    // File Upload
    if (isset($_FILES['fileToUpload'])) {
        $Errors = array();

        $File_Name = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];
        $File_Size= $_FILES['fileToUpload']['size'];
        $File_Tmp = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'];
        $File_Type = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['type'];
        $File_ext = end(explode('.',$File_Name));
        $Extensions = array('jpeg','jpg','png');
        if (in_array($File_ext,$Extensions) === false) {
            $Errors[] = "This file is not allowed to upload. You can only upload jpeg , jpg and png";
        }
        if ($File_Size > 2097152) {
            $Errors[] = "you cant upload file of size greater then 2MB";
        }
        
        if (empty($Errors) == true) {
            
            move_uploaded_file($File_Tmp,"upload/". $File_Name);
        }else{
            print_r($Errors);
            die();
        }
    }

    session_start();
    $Title = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["post_title"]);
    $Description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["postdesc"]);
    $Category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["category"]);
    $date = date("D M,Y");
    $Auther = $_SESSION['name'];

    

    $sql = "insert into post (title,description,category,post_date,author,post_img) values ('{$Title}', '{$Description}', {$Category}, '{$date}', '{$Auther}','{$File_Name}');";
    $sql .= "Update category set post = post+1 where category_id = $Category;";
    // $result =  mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql) or die ("Query unsucceful"); 
    
    if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
        mysqli_close($conn);
        
        header('Location: http://'.$hostname.'/cms/admin/post.php');
    }else {
        echo "Query Failed";
    }
    
?>
```

Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Never save the file with the filename the user provided!!! If you need the name for later, store it in a database. Create your own filename. Maybe a combination of filename, timestamp, username and a hash of it, or a uuid, or ...

Comment: How to save file with different name ? Can we generate a unique name every time for a file to save in server ?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` expects a filename where to move. So, yes, you can set a filename there. Sure, you can create a unique filename for every upload and you should - except you want to overwrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the uniqid() function to ensure that each uploaded image gets a unique name.

> ```
> move_uploaded_file($File_Tmp,"upload/".uniqid().$File_Name);
> ```